# How to initialize Tensor variable as identity matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I initialize a Tensor T as the identity matrix?

The following initializes T as a 784 by 784 matrix of zeros.

```
T = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 784]))
```

But I can't find a tf.fn that behaves as required. How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually pass numpy arrays as an argument for initial_value, so `tf.Variable(initial_value = np.identity(784))` should do what you intend to do.

Comment: I found `tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.eye(784), dtype=tf.float32))` works, but your answer is cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The tf.fn you are looking for is called [`tf.eye`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/eye). Thus, the most succinct answer is

```
T = tf.Variable(tf.eye(size))
```

Note: putting this in tf.Variable initializes learnable weights to the identity, but allows that it may be changed. If you actually just want the constant of an identity matrix, then simply use

```
T = tf.eye(size)
```

Comment: Does `tf.eye` come from the 1.1 release ? I've used `tf.diag(tf.ones(size))` for several month, and feel a little silly now ^^'

Comment: Man, Tensorflow is changing so fast that it's hard to make sense of it all, and missing one little function isn't a big deal (I like your solution, too).
As far as I can tell, it was added in [v0.12](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#eye) (at least I couldn't find it in v0.11, but I could in v0.12). https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/

Comment: Totally agree, it's not a big deal but kind of frustrating because I've searched for this function before using the `diag` tricks with the v0.11, and stay with this solution afterwise... I should pay more attention to the changelog! Thanks for crawling into the tensorflow API to bring me the answer =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't want to install numpy just for `np.identity` ?
Here is a tensorflow-only variant:

```
T = tf.Variable(tf.diag(tf.ones(size)))
```